# How to disable Postgres auto-commit in Spring Data R2DBC

Tags: postgresql, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

I see that currently, you can disable `auto-commit` on `Connection` object. But when you work with Spring Data you don't have access to `Connection` object.

Also, Postgres doesn't have this feature as part of the connection URL.

Does anyone know how to turn off it permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is a way to disable it permanently but you could go a bit low-level and use `Connection` object to set `auto-commit` feature:

```
@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

public Flux<Integer> insertSmth() {
        return Mono.from(connectionFactory.create())
                .flatMapMany(connection ->
                        Flux.from(connection.setAutoCommit(false))
                                .thenMany(connection.beginTransaction())
                                .thenMany(connection.createStatement("INSERT INTO ...").execute())
                                ...
}
```

**Edit**:
I seems propagation and reset of **Auto-Commit** and **Isolation Level** control through `TransactionDefinition` is available in Spring Data R2DBC 1.0.0 RC1.

See this thread: https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-spi/pull/95

Comment: The problem is I want it from spring data.

Comment: @MaxGrigoriev Take a look at the link added in the answer to investigate further.

Comment: As I understand there are the specs but Spring Data hasn't supported all features yet.